# Posting large JSON to my WCF Service return bad request?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that accept JSON String Entity and this is the method:

**UPDATE: I solved the problem as this wasn't related to the WCF service, but to the GSON formatting that I am using because is not formating a special character like "ù" and the server refuse to accept this character.**

```
 <WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="UpdateUser", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, Method:="POST", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)> _
Public Function UpdateUser(user As String) As Stream Implements IService1.UpdateUser

End Function
```

If I try to post trough JAVA HttpClient a JSON String with the code below and with short JSON string all work fine, but if the size of the JSON string is bigger, then the IIS 7.5 response with:

**-MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler
 Notification 128
HttpStatus 400 
 HttpReason Bad Request 
 HttpSubStatus 0 
 ErrorCode 0 
 ConfigExceptionInfo 
 Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode
Operazione completata. (0x0)**

I tried already with MaxReceivedMessageSize and other size settings in the Web.Config but without success.

This is my Web.Config file

```
 <services>
  <service name="WBVoice4Facebook.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamedRequestWebBinding" contract="WBVoice4Facebook.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
 </services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0">
      <security>
        <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StreamedRequestWebBinding" 
             openTimeout="10:15:00" 
             receiveTimeout="10:15:00" 
             sendTimeout="10:15:00" 
             bypassProxyOnLocal="true" 
             hostNameComparisonMode="WeakWildcard"
             maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
             transferMode="Streamed" 
             useDefaultWebProxy="false">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="InheritedFromHost" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a limit in asp.net Runtime.
More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)